# Excel Data Validation List from Lookup Table with Non-Contiguous Values

Tags: excel, list, lookup

I'm running into an issue with MS Excel where I'd like to create a list, populated from values in a lookup table with values that are non-contiguous.  I get an error (*"You may not use unions, intersections or array constants for Data Validation criteria."*) when trying to create a list with a source that looks LIKE

`=$C$3:$C$7,$C$9,$C$10`

Does anyone have any recommendations on creating a Data Validation List with a lookup table that has some values that are not adjacent to one another?

Many thanks!

Comment: In this simple scenario I would create another contiguous range referencing those 7 cells and assign it to validation list.

Comment: Yes, that scenario would work, but I'm hoping there is a way to join the non-contiguous cells via nested functions, rather than creating additional, dependent lookup tables based off the master lookup table.